# Adicionar filtro de usuário em uma função

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

A função abaixo emite notas fiscais automaticamente usando [este plugin (Nota Fiscal Eletrônica WooCommerce)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nota-fiscal-eletronica-woocommerce/) quando o status do pedido é concluído.

```
function issue_automatic_invoice( $order_id, $from, $to, $order ) {
    
    // Validate
    $option = apply_filters( 'nfe_issue_automatic', get_option('wc_settings_woocommercenfe_emissao_automatica') );
    if ( !$option ){
        return;
    }

    // Process
    if (
        $to == 'processing' && ($option == 1 || $option == 'yes') ||
        $to == 'completed' && $option == 2
    ){

        $nfes = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'nfe', true );

        if ( !empty($nfes) && is_array($nfes) ) {
            foreach ( $nfes as $nfe ) {
                if ( $nfe['status'] == 'aprovado' ) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        $nf = new WooCommerceNFeIssue;
        $response = $nf->send( array( $order_id ) );

    }

    do_action( 'nfe_issued_automatic', $order_id, $to, $response );

}
```

Como seria possível adicionar um `if` para não emitir se o criador do pedido for `admin`?

Quero que a função seja executada apenas nos pedidos dos clientes e não nos meus.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode buscar o CPF cadastrado no pedido a ser processado e executar a função apenas se o CPF for diferente do seu, por exemplo:

```
function issue_automatic_invoice( $order_id, $from, $to, $order ) {
    $format = new WooCommerceNFeFormat;
    $checaCPF = $format->format_number( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_cpf', true ) );
    if ( $checaCPF != 12345678900){
    
        // Validate
        $option = apply_filters( 'nfe_issue_automatic', get_option('wc_settings_woocommercenfe_emissao_automatica') );
        if ( !$option ){
            return;
        }

        // Process
        if (
            $to == 'processing' && ($option == 1 || $option == 'yes') ||
            $to == 'completed' && $option == 2
        ){

            $nfes = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'nfe', true );

            if ( !empty($nfes) && is_array($nfes) ) {
                foreach ( $nfes as $nfe ) {
                    if ( $nfe['status'] == 'aprovado' ) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            $nf = new WooCommerceNFeIssue;
            $response = $nf->send( array( $order_id ) );

        }

        do_action( 'nfe_issued_automatic', $order_id, $to, $response );     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode fazer um if antes de chamar a função:

```
if(cliente) {
    issue_automatic_invoice( $order_id, $from, $to, $order )
} else {
    die('admin')
}
```

espero ter ajudado